# Laravel order of middleware (Middleware Priority). Multi-tenant using Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, middleware, multi-tenant

In **web.php** I've switched Postgres schemas in middleware as the subdomain type of HTTP request is made. This way:

```
Route::group(
    [
        'domain'     => '{tenant}.' . config('app.url'),
        'middleware' => 'select-schema'
    ],
    function () {
        $this->get('/', 'HomeController@index')->middleware('auth');
    }
);
```

In **select-schema** middleware, I do something like this. This works correctly. (don't worry)

```
DB::select('SET search_path TO ' . {tenant});
```

My main problem is that: I've different `migrations` for `public` schema and for any `individual tenant`. In `individual tenant` I have `users` table. As soon I'm logged in it pop up this error.

> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "users" does not exist

**The main issue is**

```
$this->get('/', 'HomeController@index')->middleware('auth');
```

The model works well but middleware `auth` execute first before  `select-schema`

**How do I order?** `select-schema` then `auth`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found the solution, 
For this, there's something called `$middlewarePriority` in `App\Kernel`.

Adding this help me solve the problem.

```
/**
 * Responsible for prioritizing the middleware
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\SwitchSchema::class,
];
```

I've got solution from this link.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19565

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your routes in the tenant group with another group? See if this works:

```
Route::group([
        'domain'     => '{tenant}.' . config('app.url'),
        'middleware' => 'select-schema'
    ],function () {
        Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
            Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Yes I tried did, it doesn't work. Anyway I found the solution. Thanks.