# Route middleware priority in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In this example priority always will be: auth > mid1 > mid2?

```
Route::middleware([
    'auth',
    'mid1',
    'mid2',
])->group(function () {
    //
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel order of middleware (Middleware Priority). Multi-tenant using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487764/laravel-order-of-middleware-middleware-priority-multi-tenant-using-postgres)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a parent class there is

```
protected $middlewarePriority
```

You can override it in your app/Http/Kernel.php.